# Flutter chat bubble

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

[image: I want to create this kind of widget for chat application. How to design this in flutter. can anyone help me if you have idea]

I want to create this kind of widget for chat application. How to design this in flutter. can anyone help me if you have idea

Answer (score 0):

Check out [flutter_chat_bubble](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_chat_bubble) library.

You can adjust the properties according to your requirement.

> ```
> ChatBubble(
>     clipper: ChatBubbleClipper8(type: BubbleType.sendBubble),
>   )
>   
> ChatBubble(
>     clipper: ChatBubbleClipper8(type: BubbleType.receiverBubble),
>   )
> ```
>
> [image]

Answer (score 0):

Try below code hope its helpful to you refer `flutter_chat_bubble` package [here](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_chat_bubble) or try [this](https://pub.dev/packages/chat_bubbles) package also

```
Column(
            children: [
              ChatBubble(
                child: Text(
                  "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
                clipper: ChatBubbleClipper3(
                  type: BubbleType.sendBubble,
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 30,
              ),
              ChatBubble(
                child: Text(
                  "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
                clipper: ChatBubbleClipper3(
                  type: BubbleType.receiverBubble,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
```

Your result screen-> [image]

Comment: i want extract design