# Custom Container border in flutter for message

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-clippath

I am new in flutter i don't know how to make a custom border kindly help me to generate this type of border.

[image]

Comment: refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69808394/13997210) hope its help to you.

Comment: thank you @RavindraS.Patil

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/flutter-borderradius-widget/                                                                                                          https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69808271/flutter-chat-bubble/69808394#69808394

Comment: it's ok @RavindraS.Patil :)